# How to allow subdomain in dnsmasq

Tags: dnsmasq

In my *dnsmasq.conf* file, I use the following rule o block all domains ending with `.be`:

`address=/be/`

But I would like to have an exception for `youtu.be`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
dnsmasq -C /dev/null -k \
  --server=/youtu.be/# \
  --address=/be/ \
  --log-facility=/dev/stdout \
  --log-queries
```

From the docs for the `--server` option:

> The special server address `#` means, "use the standard servers", so `--server=/google.com/1.2.3.4 --server=/www.google.com/#` will send queries for `google.com` and its subdomains to `1.2.3.4`, except `www.google.com` (and its subdomains) which will be forwarded as usual.

With this running on my local machine:

```
# dig +short foo.be @localhost
# dig +short youtu.be @localhost
142.250.72.110
```

Comment: Yes, it works! Thank you very much.